# PrimeFaces dataExporter send csv to screen instead of save for large data

Tags: primefaces

When exporting data table to a csv format using Primefaces, if the dataset is large, the resulting csv data is displayed directly in the browser window instead of the window to Open/Save popping up.  Works as expected if the data is small, i.e. I get the pop up window with the Open/Save choices.

```
    <h:commandLink title="#{msgs.Export} CSV">
  <h:graphicImage name="#{msgs.CSVImg}" library="images"
          class="smIconStyle" />
  <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="variancesTable"
          fileName="#{msgs.VariancesDoc}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Binh

Comment: Still can't figure out the problem.  The one thing I did notice is when the dataset is small, the response header has the following lines (this is for exporting xls):  `Content-Disposition attachment;filename=Variances.xls
Content-Type application/vnd.ms-excel`; whereas when the dataset is large, these 2 lines are missing.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Found this is a known problem in Primefaces.  (http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1529)